# how to condition use with field in django using python

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements, field

Why does it not ap

```
class opportunity(models.Model):
    lead_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('...', '...'),
        ('Individual', 'Individual'),
        ('Company', 'Company'),
    ]
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='...')

    if type == 'Individual':
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    elif type == 'Company':
        Company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

pear field  based on the selection?

nothing showed up Is the condition correct?

Comment: yes, since a `CharField` is *not* a string, so both `if` conditions will be `False` when the class is constructed.

Comment: But what you aim to do is simply not a good idea.

Comment: Good or bad idea aside, I'm not even sure this is possible, assuming you are using a relational database behind the scenes. How would that table's schema look like?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a field dynamically.

Instead you can either put both fields and make them **nullable**. And then fill in the corresponding field:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
company = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

Either create two classes that inherit from a common class:

```
class Opportunity(models.Model):
    lead_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Individual(opportunity):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Company(opportunity):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

## Bonus:

In python, classes must start with a capital letter.

The word "type" is reserved in python it is a very bad practice to name these variables "type".